# Out of memory error - no heavy computation

Tags: excel, vba, memory

I have a document that I update once a week, and that contains several linked sheets. Most of the sheets are sheets with data points for each date of the week, and three sheets are summary sheets that retrieve from the data sheets.

What is done at every update is basically adding new rows to the data sheets and creating a new summary module in each of the summary sheets. The total size of the document is 900kB.

The macro I have written has worked perfectly until now, when suddenly I am getting an "out of memory"-error. I don't understand why there would be such an error for such simple tasks as adding 7 rows, filling the formulas in some of these columns (for the 7 rows) and copying
around 20-30 rows in the summary sheets.

For example, right now I am getting an error on the autofill part of

```
Range("A12:A13").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:A13")
```

I have searched online about how to fix this error but have not found anything that works. I have tried removing almost all of the old formulas (so that everything older than 2 weeks is pure values), as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/clean-workbook-less-memory) link suggested, but it does not work.

Does anyone have any tips on what can be done to solve an error like this?

Comment: Very difficult to make suggestions without examining the rest of your code. Please update your post to include the full relevant code. The reason could be your code, your device or other programs running at the same time. Have you tried running it on a different machine?

Comment: One thing you can also try is selecting all empty rows below your data. Right click and delete all of them. Then save your workbook. Does this help?

Comment: You're also talking about adding 7 rows and copying rows to summary sheet but are you adding rows from the top then since you've hardcoded the range? What's in A12's formula?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Thank you for your comment. I have tried to run the same file on my colleague's computer. I understand it is hard to examine without viewing the rest of the code, but I can't share it because of my company's security rules. However, I have a hard time it would be a problem with the code itself since I have broken the code up in small subs (meaning local variables are deleted) and also, the error happens quite early in the code. I guess I am looking for "out-of-the-box" suggestions at this point. I will try your suggestion with deleting rows below, thank you! :D

Comment: @Notus_Panda Exactly, I am adding from the top, so that the latest date is always the first row. Basically, A12 is just a date, like 2023-05-26, and A13 is 2023-05-25. So pulling up gives all the dates for the last weekend. Again, this formula is not some heavy computation or anything like that, which makes me question the error I receive entirely. I read online also that the "out of memory error" might be unrelated to memory ... for some readson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now recreated the file from an old version, and it works with the exact same data in the file and the exact same VBA code. I read in the comments of [this](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013619_Out_of_Memory_Errors_for_Macros.html) link that there could be a problem with corruption of the file. The article in the link itself also explains that there could be other things than memory-related issues that cause the "out of memory" error.

I therefore conclude that my file was corrupted somehow and that the "out of memory" error was caused by something unrelated (or at most loosely related) to using too much memory.

This argument is strengthened by the wide use of smaller subs called from one main sub (meaning local variables are deleted), and that the error popped up at places where there was no particularly heavy memory use, such as selecting a sheet or autofilling a small range with cells containing only values.

Should anyone have a similar problem in the future, try and recreate the file from an old version and see if the problem persists.